# Re-Using Datagrid In Multiple TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a WPF application that uses a TabControl.  Each TabItem will contain a datagrid.  When the application starts up, there is one TabItem that loads by default that displays an "Accounts" datagrid.  This datagrid displays only account information.  The user can then choose to add new Tabs.  For each tab that is added, I need the same datagrid to be loaded.  It is NOT the same datagrid that is used for the Accounts TabItem.  The new datagrid will be used to enter transactions.  How can I define a datagrid that I can use in each newly added TabItem, but is different than the original datagrid on the first TabItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly what you want is a default `DataGrid` for the first `tabitem` and then for each new `tabitem` same `datagrid`.

Problem here is that a single `DataGrid` cannot be part of Two `TabItems` at the same time. So what you would have to do it first declare a `DataGrid` in a scope where it can be accessed in the code behind. Next, when user adds a new `tabitem`, first time, add a `tab item` dynamically in the `tab control` and set `content` equal to `DataGrid`. When user clicks the add new tab item again, remove the `content` of tab item which previously had `DataGrid` and then Add `datagrid` in the new `tab item`. You will also have to handle the `selection change` event of tabs and inside that event you will have to remove `DataGrid` from last selected item and put in the newly selected item.

I am not sure you really need this same dataGrid for different tab items thing or not but think before implementing this approach about other possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd recommend using the MVVM pattern.

Have your main ViewModel define an `public ObservableCollection<object> Items` property.  Bind your `TabControl`'s `ItemsSource` to the `Items`.

Define a `DataTemplate` for an `AccountsViewModel` which contains the `DataGrid` which should be displayed on the Accounts `TabItem`.

Define a `DataTemplate` for a `TransactionsViewModel` which contains the `DataGrid` which should be displayed on *each* Transactions `TabItem`.

Answer (score 0):

On the `Account Tab` add in `XAML` a `DataGrid`, let's say **AccountDataGrid**

For other types, as they generated at runtime, it's better to manage them from the code.

Create `DataGrid` object that will be shared by other `TabItems`, let's say **SharedDataGrid**

After you can do something like this, for example:

Define your custom `TabItem` class

```
 public sealed class CustomTabItem : TabItem
 {
 }
```

and after override  inside that class

```
 protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
 {
    //assign shared SharedDataGrid to the content of TabItem
 }
```

In that method actually assign **SharedDataGrid** to the content of the just created and initialized `TabItem`.

*Should* work.